# BQ convert timestamp to date

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In a table a column name is col_date in format 2023-11-17 09:00:00.0
How should I convert into this format(11/17/2023) using BQ query?

I tried:
select cast(col_date as date) as col_date from table1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to convert to timestamp with [TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp) and then back to string with [FORMAT_TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#format_timestamp):

```
with test_data as (select '2023-11-17 09:00:00.0' as col_date)
select FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y', TIMESTAMP(col_date))
from test_data
```

[image]